# UWP ShareTarget View on running App

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, share

On my main application i have attached the EventHandlers "EnteringBackground" and "LeavingBackground", in These handlers, i'm running some Code. Now my app is providing a share target.

```
protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;

    if (shareOperation.Data != null)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SharePage), args.ShareOperation);
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

The Code inside my SharePage is executed in another view. So my Problem now is, when my app is already running (for example in Background), after sharing some data, my "LeavingBackgound" EventHandler is not fired anymore. So how can i Workaround this exactly?

Best Regards

Comment: Does no one have such a Problem?

Comment: What is the role of your app? Is your app share target or for showing shareUI? As you said your app provide the share target code, you also said your app can share some data to others,

Comment: It is a share target only. I mean when i share some data to my app, then these EventHandlers will not be fired anymore.

Comment: I tested the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareTarget) and cannot reproduce your issue,

Comment: This issuehappens only, if the target and min version is set to 14393 and occurs not every time. To reproduce it, open the app and let it opened. Then open for example the photos app and share a picture multiple tumes with the app. Then the both handlers (EnteredBackground and LeavingBackground) wont be fired anymore. If you can not reproduce the issue, i have made a sample project, which i can share here.